# How are one time only popups implemented?

Tags: html, cookies, popup, backend

When you return to certain websites, sometimes they have popups or messages which show to inform users of new updates to the site or important changes.

I'm having issues understanding how these are implemented because these messages only show up once. How would a backend know that a user has already seen a backup and would it not be strenuous checking every time a page is returned to if a user has seen a certain message?

There are multiple methods which I have thought of to implement this functionality:

- Storing a cookie which is checked by the backend to see if the user has seen a recent message or popup.
- Have a table in a database named 'viewed_message' or something that states all the users that have seen a certain message or not.

How would a website go about creating one-time only popup/messages? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically cookies are used for that sort of thing. Just check the existence of some `firstVisit` cookie and pop up the message if it's not there. Keep in mind this means if you clear your cookies you'll see the popup again.

edit:
This is an example from the [Document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) docs on Mozilla:

```
function doOnce() {
  if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)doSomethingOnlyOnce\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
    alert("Do something here!");
    document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the way.

Cookies are there for that, create a cookie wich never expires and be happy. 
If you want to use in wich others browsers, check if the cookies exists if dont look in table and store a cookie.